# having problems updating cron job with multiple database interactions and email

Tags: php

New server has latest php and MariaDB, existing outdated code on cron job with more than one call to and from database with email notification no longer returns expected results.

Moved to new server, website built years ago by volunteers, I have tried changing how php interacts with database using mysqli changes I have read about, worked on all other basic pages but multiple calls using sql1, sql2 etc not functioning.

```
<?php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
$headers .= "From: member@trbncom.com\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$dbh=MySQLi_connect ("localhost", "trbncom_main", "password!") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . MySQLi_error());
MySQLi_select_db ("trbncom_main");
$sql="select * from members where active='on' and mmonth='$renewalmonth' and mdate='$renewaldate'";
$result=MySQLi_query($sql); 
while($myrow=MySQLi_fetch_array($result))
{
$chapter=$myrow["chapter"];
$mdate=$myrow["mdate"];
$mmonth=$myrow["mmonth"];
$myear=$myrow["myear"];
$lname=$myrow["lname"];
$fname=$myrow["fname"];
$firstnotice=$myrow["firstnotice"];
$sent1st=$myrow["sent1st"];
$sent2nd=$myrow["sent2nd"];
$sentoverdue=$myrow["sentoverdue"];

echo("<br>$lname, $fname<br>Joined on $mmonth, $mdate, $myear<br>$chapter, CID= $cid");

    $sql2="select lname, fname, email from members where cid='$cid' and active='on' and admin='pres'";
    $result2=MySQLi_query($sql2); 
    while($myrow2=MySQLi_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    $fname2=$myrow2["fname"];
    $lname2=$myrow2["lname"];
    $email2=$myrow2["email"];

echo("<br>$lname2, $fname2<br>$email2");

mail("member@trbncom.com","$fname $lname Membership is up for Renewal","<span style='color: #000080; font-size:12px; font-family: tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'>Hello $fname<br><br>

Another year has come and gone and it's time to renew your membership
Sincerely<br>
Membership Committee<br>
</span>","$headers");

$sent=date("d M Y");
$sql3="update members set sent1st= '$sent', firstnotice='yes' where mid=$mid"; 
$result3=MySQLi_query($sql3);
}}
?>
```

The file does discover members with due dates on this day, it does email the list of members to me, it does not retrieve the sql2 query or update the table in the sql3 update.  I dumped all my previous mysqli update attempts and reverted to the original code that worked before update, and have displayed it.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that there is php code outside the `<?php` tag. That won't be executed, it will just be sent as-is to the browser.

Comment: I may have cut off the previous code when posting I think the first line is the end of the find renewal date function.  I will try to edit this.

Comment: Removed the remaining portion of the upper code, I didn't think is was important, it was a calculation to determine advanced notification for membership renewals and it still works perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using `MySQLi_query` you need to pass also the database handle `$dbh`, or link, that you established with the call to `MySQLi_connect`.

So, for example:

```
$dbh = MySQLi_connect ("localhost", "trbncom_main", "password!") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . MySQLi_error());

MySQLi_select_db ($dbh, "trbncom_main");

$sql="select * from members where active='on' and mmonth='$renewalmonth' and mdate='$renewaldate'";

$result=MySQLi_query($dbh, $sql); 

...
```

Check documentation carefully: this is easy to miss. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't believe it but that tip fixed all the mysqli code I had been trying for days.  You are awesome!  This fully works now and you have saved my life.  I have come to this page to read many tips and it has helped in updating the rest of the website, I was seriously stuck here and took a chance to sign up and ask the question, this simple answer fixed everything.  I will post the final code in case someone down the road has similar questions.

Comment: Very happy to help!

Comment: tried to update the code in my question but keeps telling me what I am trying to paste is not proper code format even with indents, I guess it stays the way it is :(

Comment: It's ok: I think it will be clear what the issue and solution is to future visitors already. Thank you!